# Django post method returns only blank values for checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox

I have tried to look around for this specific query on SO, but could not find one.

I am new to Django and am using version 1.10 and python 3.4.
For the checkboxes I am using them in the template itself.

For some reason I am hesitant in using the checkbox widget in the forms.py file, I think it will disturb my existing UI(please correct me if I am wrong).
When I submit the form, the template returns blank quotes for the number of checkboxes I have ticked.

Here is my model:

```
class UsrGrpMaster(models.Model):
    SrNo =models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    UsrGrpID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    GrpName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Purch = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    PurchMod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Sales = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    SalesMod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Stock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    StockMod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    JV = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    JVMod = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DelPurch = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DelSales = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DelJV = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "UsrGrpMaster"
```

Here is my template:

```
<div class="body-set">      
<div id="form">

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{% url 'creategroup' %}">
      <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <label class=""><font size="6">Create a New User Group</font></label>{% if errormsg %}<br />
        <font size="3" color="#FF0000">{{ errormsg }}</font>{% endif %}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="text">Name of the User Group:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="grpname" placeholder="Type in the new User Group Name" name="grpname">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="text">Permissions:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div><strong>Purchase Voucher</strong></div>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1">View</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2">Edit</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3">Delete</label>
        </div><br /><br /><br />
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="text"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div><strong>Sales Voucher</strong></div>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="4">View</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="5">Edit</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="6">Delete</label>
        </div><br /><br /><br />
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="text"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div><strong>Stock</strong></div>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="7">View</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="8">Edit</label>
        </div><br /><br /><br />
        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="text"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <div><strong>Journal Voucher / Income-Expense Voucher / Ledgers</strong></div>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="9">View</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="10">Edit</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="11">Delete</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create User Group</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the class based View:

```
class CreateGroup(View):
@never_cache
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'adminusr' in request.COOKIES:
        if request.session.get('errormsg', None):
            errormsg = request.session['errormsg']
            del request.session['errormsg']
        else:
            errormsg = ''
        return render(request, 'adminpage/creategroup.html', {"errormsg": errormsg})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/adminpage/")


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        GrpName = request.POST.get('grpname')
        chq = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')

        print(chq)
        value = sninc(UsrGrpMaster, 'SrNo') #increments the sn and stores in DB

        if checkduplicates(UsrGrpMaster, 'GrpName', GrpName) is not True:
            qs = UsrGrpMaster(SrNo=value, GrpName=GrpName,
                                 Purch=chq[1],
                                 PurchMod=chq[2],
                                 Sales=chq[4],
                                 SalesMod=chq[5],
                                 Stock=chq[7],
                                 StockMod=chq[8],
                                 JV=chq[9],
                                 JVMod=chq[10],
                                 DelPurch=chq[3],
                                 DelSales=chq[6],
                                 DelJV=chq[11]
                                )
            qs.save()
        else:
            request.session['errormsg'] = "The user group already exists"
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/adminpage/adminhome/creategroup/")

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/adminpage/adminhome/")
```

Here is the browser and console clipping. Checked 9 boxes and submit shows 9 empty quotes.
[template_browser_clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ikOB.png)
[console_clipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTudn.png)

I want the form to provide me the value property of the checked boxes so I can store them in the database. Please guide me as to how to achieve this (with or without using forms.py).

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').submit(function() {
    if ($.trim($('input[name="grpname"]').val()) === "") {
      $('input[name="grpname"]').css({'background-color' : '#ffe5e5'});
      return false;
    }
  });


   $('input').focusin(function() {
      $(this).css({'background-color' : '#ffffff'});
   });

   $('input').blur(function() {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) === "") {
         $(this).css({'background-color' : '#ffe5e5'});
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: What you've posted here should work; note that it's correctly printing the same number of empty strings as selected checkboxes. Are you sure this is the real template code, and those are the real values in the `value` attributes of each element?

Comment: (Note also, there's no need to use brackets in the input name; that's a practice from PHP/Rails, and isn't standard HTML or idiomatic Python.)

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yes, the template code provided here is a snippet of the actual template code. The post function gives the number of checkboxes checked but how can I deduce from the list which ones were checked ? The values that I am trying to save using chq[] are of no use. I have commented them and the objects are saved as False by default.

Comment: If this was your real code, then the value of `chq` would be `['1', '2', '3' ...]` etc.

Comment: That's what I fail to understand. The code mentioned here is the actual code without any modifications, but why isn't it showing me a numbered list.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript on this page?

Comment: Yes, I have used javascript on this page. The input box background turns red if empty. Please refer to the code I have mentioned above and let me know if there is something wrong with it.